# Running multiple Cypher commands under Windows

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to import data from a relational database into Neo4j. I am running the current version, 3.2, under Windows.

My problem is that I cannot run the multiple commands necessary to the task. The browser is strictly a command-at-a-time, and while the console seems to accept multiple commands, I cannot get the file syntax right for importing a .CSV file (it is different that of the browser or even the cypher shell). And the shell itself seems to fall over with distressing regularity.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

The start of the import process looks like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (d:DeployableUnit) ASSERT d.Deployable_unit_id IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (f:Feature) ASSERT f.Featuret_id IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///seshatdata/sellable_unit_features.csv" AS line WITH line
WITH line, SPLIT(line.ship_dt, '-') as date

CREATE (deployableunit:DeployableUnit {Deployable_unit_id: line.Deployable_unit_id})
CREATE (feature:Feature {Feature_id:line.Featuret_id});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple commands in the Neo4j Browser. The keyboard shortcut `Shift + Enter` will enter in the multiline mode, as described [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_useful_commands_and_keyboard_shortcuts).

So you can press `Ctrl + Enter` to run queries in multiline mode.

This way you can run your import script into Neo4j browser.